# MyBatis java and MySql local variables

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, ibatis, mybatis

I'm new to java world. And I have a problem with simple query:

```
<insert id="create" parameterType="models.entities.CategoryEntity">

    set @catId := (select categoryId from Categories limit 1);
     insert into Categories(CategoryId, Title, LeftValue, RightValue)
    values(@catId, 'Test in', 1,2);
   ....
</insert>
```

it simply fails when i trying to run it with mybatis:

```
PersistenceException occured : ### Error updating database. Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert into Categories(CategoryId, Title, LeftValue, RightValue) values(' at line 2 ### The error may involve Category.create-Inline ### The error occurred while setting parameters ### Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert into Categories(CategoryId, Title, LeftValue, RightValue) values(' at line 2
```

If I remove this line:

```
set @catId := (select categoryId from Categories limit 1);
```

then everything is ok. What am i doing wrong? Is it problem with jdbc or mybatis? How to use mysql @variables with mybatis? Does someone have examples of using MySql local variables with mybatis?

Comment: When you run the query `select categoryId from Categories limit 1` against the DB does it fail?

Comment: 2David: it works just fine against the DB

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found out how to get it worked. Just set datasource property allowMultiQueries=true

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DBS?allowMultiQueries=true
```

Comment: This works for sybase too. Thanks Tim for saving Tim(e)